# NSString EXC_BAD_ACCESS in stringByReplacingOcurrencesOfString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS every time I run this code I cant figure out what is happening. The error jumps when I use stringByReplacingOcurrencesOfString.

```
- (IBAction)buttonSign:(id)sender {

    if (!negative) {
        number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",number];

        negative = true;
    }
    else if (negative){
        number= [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

        negative = false;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",number);
}
```

Comment: Apart from the `else if (negative)` being redundant, your logic is mixed up (you add a negative sign if the `negative` flag is not set...)

Comment: Sorry for that, either way the logic is working well. The real problem is jumping when I try to remove the negative sign.

Comment: What is `number` set to when you try to remove the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `stringWithFormat` api, it is not correct. So try this two options below :-

**First option you can use this**

```
number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"-",number];
```

**Second option you can use this `stringByAppendingString` api as well**

```
NSString *negNo=@"-";

number = [negNo stringByAppendingString:number];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", negative?@"-":@"",number];
negative = !negative;
```